# Dagger vs a setter for testing

Tags: java, android, dependency-injection, dagger

I am really just getting started with android testing and I am realizing that dependencies are hard to test.  For my first couple of tests I used a setter to inject a mock object, but after reading some about Dagger, I am considering using it.  Below is an example of some of the tests I currently have.

In this case the method I am trying to test has a dependency on a marker Object.  I added a setter for that object.  To test the method, I build two different versions of the dependent object each with a different mock of the marker Object.

As I said I have done some reading about dependency injection and Dagger, and I think I understand how I can have a Module for production and an overriding Module for test, but I am beginning to think to accomplish the same thing as below with Dagger, I would need three different modules.

1. Production module - provides real object
2. Test module1 - provides mock object configured to return
   hasAccuracy() = false and getAccurracy = null
3. Test module2 - provides mock object configured to return
   hasAccuracy() = true and getAccruacy = 44.0f

Would I really need 3 different modules for this, or am I missing something?
Does it make sense to convert something like this to use Dagger rather than setters?
If so, can someone provide some direction on how to go about this?

```
    @Test 
    public void testGetGoogleMapMarkerParametersWithoutAccuracy() {
        when(mockRailsMarker.hasAccuracy()).thenReturn(false);
        when(mockRailsMarker.getAccuracy()).thenReturn(null);
        MapMarker androidMapMarker = new MapMarkerBuilder().withBus(mockBus)
                .withMarker(mockRailsMarker)
                .build();
        assertThat(androidMapMarker.getGoogleMapMarkerParameters().getCircleRadius()).as("radius is zero").isEqualTo(0.0f);

    }

    @Test 
    public void testGetGoogleMapMarkerParametersWithAccuracy() {
        when(mockRailsMarker.hasAccuracy()).thenReturn(true);
        when(mockRailsMarker.getAccuracy()).thenReturn(44.0f);
        MapMarker androidMapMarker = new MapMarkerBuilder().withBus(mockBus)
                .withMarker(mockRailsMarker)
                .build();
        assertThat(androidMapMarker.getGoogleMapMarkerParameters().getCircleRadius()).as("has a valid radius").isEqualTo(44.0f);

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I found the solution to this on my own.

In my question above I am testing a method that has a dependency on an instance of a class called `RailsMapMarker`  The way I was satisfying that dependency was to create a mock and "inject" it via a setter method during the MapMarkerBuild process.

To do the same thing with Dagger here is what I would do. I say would, because It turns out that this particular object could already be passed in via a constructor, so this is more of an example based on what I did for another dependency.

First I create 2 modules one for production and one for test.

The production one would look something like this (this goes in your main project)

```
@Module(injects = MapMarker.class)
public class AFirstDaggerModule {

    @Provides
    RailsMapMarker provideRailsMapMarker() {
        System.out.println("inside dagger -non mock");
        return new RailsMapMarker();

    }

}
```

and the test one like this (note the @Singleton annotation, this injects the same instance into both the test class and the class under test) which is key. (this goes in your test project)

```
@Module(injects = { MapMarker.class, MapMarkerTest.class })
public class AFirstDaggerModule {

    @Provides @Singleton
    RailsMapMarker provideRailsMapMarker() {
        System.out.println("inside dagger - mock");
        return mock(RailsMapMarker.class);

    }

}
```

In both the MapMarker class and the MapMarkerTest class I have an annotated field.

MapMarker class

```
@Inject
RailsMapMarker railsMapMarker;
```

MapMarkerTest class

```
@Inject
RailsMapMarker mockRailsMapMarker;
```

In my Application class I have a field where I create the graph and a getter for the graph

```
private static ObjectGraph objectGraph;

public static ObjectGraph getObjectGraph() {
    return objectGraph;
}
```

in the onCreate method for the application I have:

```
    objectGraph = ObjectGraph.create(new AFirstDaggerModule());
```

where AFirstDaggerModule is the name of the Module in both the app and test projects

Then in both the constructor for the class I am testing **and** in the setUp() method of the test class I have this:

```
    MyApp.getObjectGraph().inject(this);
```

After all this when I run my test I have an injected mock in my the instance I am testing **and** I have a field (mockRailsMarker) in my test class which is a reference to that same mock because the same instance of the mock was injected into both fields (due to the @Singleton annotation).

This means I don't need a setter for the RailsMapMaker object inside my MapMarker class, since it is now injected by Dagger, and I have full control over the behavior of the mock from my testcase.

I know this is probably pretty basic to people that normally use Dagger and mocks, but I struggled with this for a while, and I never really found anything that had all the details in one place.  Most of the stuff I found assumed you knew most of the pieces and showed one piece of the puzzle.

Anyway I hope this helps someone else, otherwise I will at least be able to comeback and refresh my memory when this all fades away.